# ~/.rvm/bin/rvm is not a function but rvm is

Tags: rvm, capistrano, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

```
ubuntu@server1:~$ type ~/.rvm/bin/rvm | head -1
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/rvm is /home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/rvm

ubuntu@server1:~$ which rvm
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/rvm

ubuntu@server1:~$ type rvm | head -1
rvm is a function

ubuntu@server1:~$ type `which rvm` | head -1
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/rvm is /home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/rvm
```

Running RVM works okay when you're ssh'ed into the box, but capistrano throws out `RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.` errors because capistrano is using `~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do $command` and it kind of bothers me. Deploying seems to work though.

I don't think this is related to Capistrano, but for reference here's part of my Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '3.0.1'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '1.1.2'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '1.1.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm', '0.1.1'
end
```

Basically, my questions are

1. Is RVM behaving properly?
2. How do I suppress the capistrano error if I shouldn't be worried?